# Customizing msbuild for .NET Core with something like CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, hook, customization

For a long time, I have been very successful at non-invasively customizing many .NET Framework builds by setting `CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets` and `CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets` as environment variables in a command-line shell that corresponds to a given development/build workspace.

I would set these environment variables to point to custom msbuild targets files that would then be automatically imported (before and after respectively) the import of the standard Microsoft provided targets files. This has worked great for a long time, but now .NET Core comes along and I find no mechanism quite like that.

I am aware of `Directory.Build.props` and that does not appear to be equivalent. For one, it is invasive requiring me to add a file to a source tree that I don't want to necessarily touch in order to customize its build (maybe its an open source project and I don't want to be injecting new files into it). For two, it doesn't provide the dual Before/After import hooks which are very important (if this duality weren't important Microsoft would never have provided it).

I also don't like dropping magic files in magic global locations as my build policies/customizations are themselves versioned source code which can vary from one developer workspace to another (even on the very same machine for the very same developer).

It seems odd that Microsoft would fail to retain such a long-standing and fundamentally useful msbuild customization capability in .NET Core. Am I missing an equivalently powerful, easy to use and non-invasive mechanism? Is it there and I just haven't found it?

Answer (score 0):

`CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets` and `CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets` are still part of MSBuild 15 which is included in VS 2017 and the .NET Core SDK.

Setting them as global variables will still import them and override the default locations used if not set. Use the `/bl` argument to generate a binary build log and the [MSBuild structured log viewer](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog) to diagnose issues you may have with it.